# How to define all musical note names .. Cbb Cb C Cs Css .. as constructors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I was playing with musical note names having the goal to not confuse enharmonic equals, i.e. I wanted to get the accidentals (sharps and flats) right. The note a perfect fifth above the note `B` needs to be `Fs` and not `Gb`, even though `Fs` and `Gb` are the same key on a piano keyboard.

Also I wanted the convenience of writing e.e. `Fs` in a haskell program, *without spaces, quotes or an extra function*.

I ended up defining 35 constructors, ranging from `Cbb` to `Bss`. While this worked and did get the accidentals right, I was unhappy about the limitation to at most two accidentals. Internally, the accidentals we represented as`Int`s anyways.

- Is there a way to define an infinite number of constructors as indicated in the title, so notes with any number of accidentals (like  `Cbbbb`) could be used? Template haskell maybe?
- Or alternatively, can I get the convenience of writing `Cbbbb` in a haskell program (*without quotes, spaces or an extra function*) without making `Cbbbb` a constructor?

Comment: not an actual answer to your question but a remark: I modelled this a couple of times and I don't think you should put this into the types (you'll regret later for example if you want to derive scales where you want to switch enharmonics so that each base-note is listed exactly once) - I would model this as an ADT/Tuple with one part the base-note and one the accidential (flat, natural, sharp) and then implement functions to test on equality modulo enharmonics and one to list all enharmonics

Comment: more to the actual question: you could model it as `(Note, SharpCount)` where `SharpCount = Int` or you could make `data Sharp a = Sharp a` and add as many `Sharp` Constructors as you want - you could go as far and use type-families to make a relation happen at the type-level - IMO this is overengineering of the problem though

Comment: You might know that there is a whole book to teach Haskell thru music and conversely. Author: Paul Hudak. The PDF file (350 pages) is freely available. [The Haskell School of Music](https://www.cs.yale.edu/~hudak/Papers/HSoM.pdf)

Comment: Instead of quotes, perhaps overloaded labels could be used https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_labels.html but a prefix hash like #bss would still be required.

Comment: Why is "without quotes, spaces, or an extra function" such an emphatic requirement? You're going to twist yourself into a pretzel trying to meet it when there are perfectly idiomatic solutions that are very convenient, despite breaking it.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Carsten that actually having lots of disperate constructors like that is a bad idea. It's much more sensible to use data like

```
data BaseNote = C | D | E | F | G | A | B
data PitchClass = PitchClass
  { baseNote :: BaseNote
  , accidentals :: Int }
data Note = Note
  { pitchClass :: PitchClass
  , octave :: Int }
```

As for

> Also I wanted the convenience of writing e.e. `Fs` in a haskell program, without spaces, quotes or an extra function.

you have multiple options.

- You could use `-XPatternSynonyms`. This lets you procure matchable constructors for already-defined data types.

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
  pattern Cn = PitchClass C 0
  pattern Cs = PitchClass C 1
  pattern Cb = PitchClass C (-1)
  ...
  ```

  These can be provided by a TemplateHaskell macro to avoid code duplication.
- You could provide a function that makes it *look* as compact as single constructor names, but actually isn't.

  ```
  (♮), (♯), (♭) :: BaseNote -> Int -> Note
  bn♮octv = Note (PitchClass bn 0) octv
  bn♯octv = Note (PitchClass bn 1) octv
  bn♭octv = Note (PitchClass bn (-1)) octv
  ```

  Now you can write things like

  ```
  [A♮2, A♮2, C♯3, C♯3, D♮3, D♮3, C♯3]
  ```

TBH I don't think either of these is really good though. IMO it makes more sense to specify musical material not in absolute pitches at all, but rather as a sequence of either *scale degrees* or *interval steps*.

Comment: I am doing all my calculations with a PitchClass like you describe. My issue is entirely cosmetic. On the output side a suitable Show instance would solve everything. But I'd also like to specify a PitchClass value without too much noise and with any number of accidentals (I  overemphasized "constructors" a bit, sorry). I cannot use read without writing read or can I? How does Integer cope with any number of digits?